# 2-way communication with C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am trying to have 2 way communication running between C sockets.  For having the sockets set up, I was following the instructions on this link (http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) and everything worked fine.  Sending messages from the client to the server worked perfectly.

However, I would also like the ability of the server to send response messages back to the client.  How is this accomplished?  If I set up a client and server connection at both ends, one of them cannot bind.

**edit** more code.  Currently, I've used this style of sockets and put them into c++ code, just because that's my familiarity.  Ignore the object oriented-ness.

```
//main call
if (server)
    {
        Connection recv(true, "servername");
        recv.GetMsg();
        recv.SendMsg("test", 4);
    }
    else // client
    {
        Connection snd(false, "servername");
        snd.GetMsg();
        snd.SendMsg("this is a test", 14);
    }
```

And inside the Connection class,

```
void SendMsg(char *msg, int msg_length)
{
        send(some_socket, msg, msg_length, 0);
};

void GetMsg()
{
        recvd = recv(opponent_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        buffer[recvd] = '\0';
        cout << "Printing msg: " << buffer << endl;
};

Connection::Connection(bool isserver, char *servername)
{
    is_server = isserver;
    server = servername;
    opponent_socket = 0;
    some_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (some_socket < 0)
    {
        cout << "Connection failed.\n" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (is_server)
    {
        AddrSetupServer(); // standard calls here.  Pretty well what's shown in link provided
        BindServer();
        ListenServer();
        WaitConnectionServer();
    }
    else
    {
        AddrSetupClient();
        ConnectClient();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a connection, it is bidirectional; simply send your response over the socket.

Comment: In the exact same method as the client code would send a response?  I get "Broken pipe" when I try that.

Comment: And in a different scenario of trying this, I get mumbled garbage, rather than the message sent.

Comment: Is the client reading responses?  If it just sends stuff and closes the socket/exits, of course you will get an error trying to respond to a client that isn't there any more.  Also, it would help if you added your code to the question.

Comment: So what I see here is that both ends first `GetMsg` and then `SendMsg`.  One of them should `SendMsg` *first* for the other to `GetMsg`, then `GetMsg` to receive the response `SendMsg`.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  I was just playing with things before the copy paste.  This is how it normally is.  The server object will get the correct "this is a test", while the client one will receive a stream of "X?/" and loop infinitely.

Comment: One thing I'd worry about is you `RecvMsg` the full size of the buffer but don't leave space for the `\0` string terminator.  You don't show the declaration of `buffer` so I can't tell if this presents an actual problem in your test program or not, but in a real program it would cause problems. Aside from that, `send` and `recv` aren't normally used on `SOCK_STREAM` sockets; they're intended for streams, not datagrams. (But again this shouldn't break your sample program.)

Comment: I would like this to use streams, not datagrams.  The buffer is a simple 30 character array.  This doesn't look like a problem?

Comment: So why are you using datagram-oriented I/O?  You should be promoting the sockets to `fstream`s and using them as such, not sending datagrams over them.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but it seems to be a stream, I thought.  Hm.  I wish to be communicating over TCP

Comment: You *are* communicating over TCP.  But you're using functions intended for UDP on a TCP stream.  Don't use them; you're supposed to use `read()` and `write()` on a stream, or better yet promote it to the proper language stream (a `FILE *` in C, an `fstream` in C++) and use it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I apparently have some more reading to do.  I appreciate it